# Error File not found: 'CheckDoc.D32'

Tags: delphi, compilation

I'm trying to compile a Delphi project made by a work colleague and I'm receiving the following compilation error:

[Error] File not found: 'CheckDoc.D32'

I searched the project and couldn't find any reference to "CheckDoc" in it. Also, I searched Google and couldn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone have an idea on what this error could be?

Thanks!

Comment: "File not found" means what it says.  Something in one of your source files (including your .Dpr file) is prompting the compiler to look for that file:  It is mostly likely the name of a resource file, an include file or something like that.  It may not necessarily be in one of the files expressly included in the project, it could be in a file which is Used by one of them.  Try doing a `Search : Find in files: Search in directories` rather than `Search all files in project`

Comment: You're trying to compile code and don't understand what the error *File not found* means? Ask your work colleague to provide you with the files necessary to compile the project. *CheckDoc.D32* is not a file that is distributed with Delphi or RAD Studio.

Comment: Surely I know what "File not found" means. :) When a message like that appears, usually there is a reference to a nonexistent file somewhere in project, and that's what I'm having trouble to find in my case... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happened that I couldn't find the reference even using Notepad++ search, but then we here found out that CheckDoc.D32 was a missing file in my $(DELPHI)\Lib, I had to copy from a colleague's machine and the code compiled. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't useful to anyone else. Please delete the entire post in the interests of future readers.